# class, interface, or enum expected java compile error

Tags: class, methods, interface, call

my assignment was to write code that display the temp table and a method to convert fahrenheit to celsius. This is my code so far. I can't seem to figure out whats wrong

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class temperature
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            double fah;
            int choice;
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
            do
            {
                    tempTable();
                    System.out.println("Enter degrees in Fahrenheit");
                    System.out.println("and I will convert it to Celsius");
                    fah = keyboard.nextDouble();

                    convert(fah);

                    System.out.println(formatter.format(fah) + " degrees Fahrenheit is        " + formatter.format(cel) + " degrees Celsius");
                    System.out.println("Press 1 to continue");
                    System.out.println("Press 2 to exit");
                    choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            }while(choice!=2);
    }
}


/**
   tempTable displays the fahrenheit to celsius temperature table
*/

public static void tempTable()
{
    System.out.println("Celsius Temperature Table\n");
    System.out.println("Fahrenheit\tCelsius\n");
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 0.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 1.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 2.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 3.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 4.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 5.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 6.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 7.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 8.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 9.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 10.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 11.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 12.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 13.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 14.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 15.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 16.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 17.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 18.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n", 19.0);
    System.out.printf("%3.1f\n\n", 20.0);
}

/**
   celsius returns degrees in fahrenheit
   @param fah degrees in fahrenheit enter by user
   @return returns degrees in celsius
*/

 public static double convert(double fah)
 {
      double cel;

      cel = (fah-32)5/9;

      return cel;
 }
```

I get the class, interface, enum expected error when i compile the code through terminal.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Is this not how to write methods?

Answer (score 0):

You prematurely closed your class `temperature` (which should have been `Temperature` by the Java naming convention). Also, your `convert` method was using integer division and you missed the multiplication operand.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double fah;
    int choice;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    do {
        tempTable();
        System.out.println("Enter degrees in Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("and I will convert it to Celsius");
        fah = keyboard.nextDouble();

        double cel = convert(fah); // <-- declare cel.
        System.out.println(formatter.format(fah)
                + " degrees Fahrenheit is        " + formatter.format(cel)
                + " degrees Celsius");
        System.out.println("Press 1 to continue");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to exit");
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while (choice != 2);
} // <-- only one brace after while, the other methods should be in the class.

/**
 * celsius returns degrees in fahrenheit
 * 
 * @param fah
 *            degrees in fahrenheit enter by user
 * @return returns degrees in celsius
 */

public static double convert(double fah) {
    double cel = (fah - 32) * ((double) 5 / 9); /* <-- multiply. 
                                                       not integer math. */
    return cel;
}
```